# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation does not exist LINE 1

Tags: django, sqlite, heroku, migration, psql

I encountered an issue while migrating a DB using django:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
> line 84, in _execute
> return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "myBlog_category" does not
> exist LINE 1: ...g_category"."name", "myBlog_category"."name" FROM
> "myBlog_ca...
> ^
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 22, in
>
> main()   File "manage.py", line 18, in main
> execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management_*init*_.py",
> line 401, in execute_from_command_line
> utility.execute()   File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management_*init*_.py",
> line 395, in execute
> self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
> line 330, in run_from_argv
> self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
> line 368, in execute
> self.check()   File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
> line 392, in check
> all_issues = checks.run_checks(   File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py",
> line 70, in run_checks
> new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)   File
> "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py",
> line 13, in check_url_config
> return check_resolver(resolver)   File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py",
> line 23, in check_resolver
> return check_method()   File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py",
> line 408, in check
> for pattern in self.url_patterns:   File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py",
> line 48, in **get**
> res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)   File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py",
> line 589, in url_patterns
> patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)   File
> "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py",
> line 48, in **get**
> res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)   File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py",
> line 582, in urlconf_module
> return import_module(self.urlconf_name)   File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib_*init*_.py",
> line 127, in import_module
> return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 1014, in _gcd_import   File
> "", line 991, in _find_and_load   File
> "", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> File "", line 671, in _load_unlocked
> File "", line 783, in
> exec_module   File "", line 219, in
> *call_with_frames_removed   File "C:\Users\rroct\Desktop\blog_Py_PostSQL\blog\blog\urls.py", line 8, in
>
> path('', include('myBlog.urls')),   File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py",
> line 34, in include
> urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)   File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib_*init**.py",
> line 127, in import_module
> return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 1014, in _gcd_import   File
> "", line 991, in _find_and_load   File
> "", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> File "", line 671, in _load_unlocked
> File "", line 783, in
> exec_module   File "", line 219, in
> _call_with_frames_removed   File "C:\Users\rroct\Desktop\blog_Py_PostSQL\blog\myBlog\urls.py", line 2,
> in 
> from .views import HomeView, ArticleDetailView, AddPostView, UpdatePostView, DeletePostView, AddCategoryView, CategoryView,
> CategoryListView, LikeView, AddCommentView   File
> "C:\Users\rroct\Desktop\blog_Py_PostSQL\blog\myBlog\views.py", line 4,
> in 
> from .forms import PostForm, EditForm, CommentForm   File "C:\Users\rroct\Desktop\blog_Py_PostSQL\blog\myBlog\forms.py", line 6,
> in 
> for item in choices:   File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py",
> line 287, in **iter**
> self._fetch_all()   File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py",
> line 1303, in _fetch_all
> self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))   File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py",
> line 142, in **iter**
> return compiler.results_iter(tuple_expected=True, chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)   File
> "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py",
> line 1108, in results_iter
> results = self.execute_sql(MULTI, chunked_fetch=chunked_fetch, chunk_size=chunk_size)   File
> "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py",
> line 1156, in execute_sql
> cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
> line 98, in execute
> return super().execute(sql, params)   File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
> line 66, in execute
> return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)   File
> "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
> line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
> return executor(sql, params, many, context)   File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
> line 84, in _execute
> return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py",
> line 90, in **exit**
> raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value   File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
> line 84, in _execute
> return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "myBlog_category" does not
> exist LINE 1: ...g_category"."name", "myBlog_category"."name" FROM
> "myBlog_ca...

I deployed the app to heroku and got errors so I tried to change the sqlite db to psql before commiting it to heroku but after doing [this](https://medium.com/djangotube/django-sqlite-to-postgresql-database-migration-e3c1f76711e1) tutorial migrations did not work anymore, I got stuck on the 3rd step of the tutorial.

I tried the following:

1. Delete migrations folder from myBlog
2. Delete db.sqlite3 file
3. After removing the files/folders above I tried python manage.py makemigrations and got the following error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
> ```
>
> line 84, in _execute
> return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
> psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "myBlog_category" does not exist
> LINE 1: ...g_category"."name", "myBlog_category"."name" FROM "myBlog_ca...
> ^
>
> ```
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
>     main()
>   File "manage.py", line 18, in main
>     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
>   File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py",
> ```
>
> line 401, in execute_from_command_line
> utility.execute()
> File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management_*init*_.py",
> line 395, in execute
> self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
> File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
> line 330, in run_from_argv
> self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
> File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
> line 368, in execute
> self.check()
> File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
> line 392, in check
> all_issues = checks.run_checks(
> File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py",
> line 70, in run_checks
> new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
> File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py",
> line 13, in check_url_config
> return check_resolver(resolver)
> File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py",
> line 23, in check_resolver
> return check_method()
> File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py",
> line 408, in check
> for pattern in self.url_patterns:
> File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py",
> line 48, in **get**
> res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)
> File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py",
> line 589, in url_patterns
> patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
> File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py",
> line 48, in **get**
> res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)
> File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py",
> line 582, in urlconf_module
> return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
> File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib_*init*_.py",
> line 127, in import_module
> return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
> File "", line 1014, in _gcd_import
> File "", line 991, in _find_and_load
> File "", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> File "", line 671, in _load_unlocked
> File "", line 783, in exec_module
> File "", line 219, in *call_with_frames_removed
> File "C:\Users\rroct\Desktop\blog_Py_PostSQL\blog\blog\urls.py", line 8, in 
> path('', include('myBlog.urls')),
> File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py",
> line 34, in include
> urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
> File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib_*init**.py",
> line 127, in import_module
> return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
> File "", line 1014, in _gcd_import
> File "", line 991, in _find_and_load
> File "", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> File "", line 671, in _load_unlocked
> File "", line 783, in exec_module
> File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
> File "C:\Users\rroct\Desktop\blog_Py_PostSQL\blog\myBlog\urls.py", line 2,
> in 
> from .views import HomeView, ArticleDetailView, AddPostView, UpdatePostView, DeletePostView, AddCategoryView, CategoryView,
> CategoryListView, LikeView, AddCommentView
> File "C:\Users\rroct\Desktop\blog_Py_PostSQL\blog\myBlog\views.py", line 4,
> in 
> from .forms import PostForm, EditForm, CommentForm
> File "C:\Users\rroct\Desktop\blog_Py_PostSQL\blog\myBlog\forms.py", line 6,
> in 
> for item in choices:
> File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py",
> line 287, in **iter**
> self._fetch_all()
> File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py",
> line 1303, in _fetch_all
> self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
> File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py",
> line 142, in **iter**
> return compiler.results_iter(tuple_expected=True, chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
> File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py",
> line 1108, in results_iter
> results = self.execute_sql(MULTI, chunked_fetch=chunked_fetch, chunk_size=chunk_size)
> File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py",
> line 1156, in execute_sql
> cursor.execute(sql, params)
> File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
> line 98, in execute
> return super().execute(sql, params)
> File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
> line 66, in execute
> return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
> File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
> line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
> return executor(sql, params, many, context)
> File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
> line 84, in _execute
> return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
> File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py",
> line 90, in **exit**
> raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
> File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
> line 84, in _execute
> return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "myBlog_category" does not exist
> LINE 1: ...g_category"."name", "myBlog_category"."name" FROM "myBlog_ca...

4. Trying to run the server locally now, doesn't work.

While deploying it to heroku I got ProgrammingError - something close to what I get now. I tried to run:

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

But got the app would return me the same error as the same traceback at the begging of the post.

My settings.py file:

```
"""
Django settings for blog project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""
import os
import django_heroku
import dj_database_url
from decouple import config
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-97gr5qi*888x%%n!=yp(uf*xz!8(jucnfd!ln+_zkyg@8#e5th'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myBlog',
    'members',
    'ckeditor',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware'
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'blog.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'blog.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE' : 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME' : 'my_db',
        'USER' : 'hero',
        'PASSWORD' : 'my_db @ 123',
        'HOST' : 'localhost',
        'PORT' : '5432',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'

LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

For any other additional required informations please let me know.

Edit 1:
My models.py

```
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self) :
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self) :
        return reverse('home')


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField()
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/profile")
    website_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    facebook_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    instagram_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    twitter_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    pinterest_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)

    def get_absolute_url(self) :
        return reverse('home')


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    header_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/")
    title_tag = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    post_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='uncategorized')
    snippet = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='blog_posts')

    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ' | ' + str(self.author)
# Create your models here.

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('article-detail', args=(str(self.id),))


class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="comments", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.post.title, self.name)
```

views.py for myBlog app:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from .models import Post, Category, Comment
from .forms import PostForm, EditForm, CommentForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy, reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
# Create your views here.


def LikeView(request, pk):
    post = Post.objects.get(id=pk)
    liked = False
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
        liked = False
    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        liked = True

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('article-detail', args=[str(pk)]))


class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'home.html'
    ordering = ['-post_date']

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cat_menu = Category.objects.all()
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context["cat_menu"] = cat_menu
        return context


class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'article_details.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cat_menu = Category.objects.all()
        context = super(ArticleDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        stuff = get_object_or_404(Post, id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        liked = False
        if stuff.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            liked = True
        total_likes = stuff.total_likes()
        context["cat_menu"] = cat_menu
        context["total_likes"] = total_likes
        context["liked"] = liked
        return context


class AddPostView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'add_post.html'


def CategoryListView(request):
    cat_menu_list = Category.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'category_list.html', {'cat_menu_list': cat_menu_list})


def CategoryView(request, cats):
    category_posts = Post.objects.filter(category=cats.title().replace('-', ' '))
    return render(request, 'categories.html', {'cats': cats.title().replace('-', ' '), 'category_posts': category_posts})


class AddCategoryView(CreateView):
    model = Category
    fields = '__all__'
    template_name = 'add_category.html'


class UpdatePostView(UpdateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'update_post.html'
    form_class = EditForm


class DeletePostView(DeleteView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'delete_post.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')


class AddCommentView(CreateView):
    model = Comment
    form_class = CommentForm
    template_name = 'add_comment.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.post_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        return super().form_valid(form)

    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have deleted the migrations folder. Add this folder to your application and add the init file to it. Then create migrations locally. You have to create migrations locally. Heroku should not (and will not) create migration files. Heroku is just executing your code.
Also, if the data in the database is not important, you can re-create db to update the migration table. Or you can update it manually.

**Steps**

`1. Creating a migration folder`

```
cd ./your_app
mkdir migrations
cd migrations
touch __ini__.py
```

`2. Creating migrations`

```
./manage.py makemigrations
```

`3. Pushing on heroku`

`4. Applying migrations`

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

P.S: I think Heroku has the tools to manage the Django app. Please refer to the documentation. I think applying migrations should be automatic.

**You should performing steps 1-3 locally.**

You can re-create the database on heroku or reset it. If you are re-creating the database, do not forget to change the access parameters in the project settings

Comment: I will try tomorrow this, my database data isn't something relevant so I can wipe it all before deploying it to heroku but wish I knew how I can I do that. 
Let me get straight what you told me, get the migrations folder back in the app -> makemigrations -> migrate?

Comment: I tried the solution you suggested, the results are the the following:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rroct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "myBlog_category" does not exist
LINE 1: ...g_category"."name", "myBlog_category"."name" FROM "myBlog_ca...


I made steps 1 and 2, create an empty folder in myapp folder -> create the __init__.py file (empty) with touch, try to makemigrations locally.

Comment: @OctavianAntoniuRăducanu Is there a model of categories? Also, it is necessary that the category model creation migration is in the dependencies of the blog table creation migration. Also, if the category model is in another app, you must add that app to INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: I edited the original post with models.py. The model is not in the another app.

Comment: @OctavianAntoniuRăducanu  1). Are migrations applied locally on your computer?
2). Have you changed the default database credentials after re-create heroku db?
3). The error clearly indicates that the migration with the category table has not been applied. Try to execute `python manage.py migrate` through the terminal in the dashboard on heroku

Comment: 1. I've done the migrations locally.
2. Done that as far as I know.
3. I executed `heroku run python manage.py migrate` and got this error:
_Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "myBlog_category" does not exist
LINE 1: ...g_category"."name", "myBlog_category"."name" FROM "myBlog_ca..._
The app was deployed here: https://thawing-mountain-44179.herokuapp.com

Comment: @OctavianAntoniuRăducanu Try the following: `heroku run python manage.py migrate myBlog zero` And then run migrate again `heroku run python manage.py migrate`. This should zero out your application migrations. Also, how many migration files are in your application?

Comment: @OctavianAntoniuRăducanu Show me models from members app. Or if you are pre-filling this table in some kind of migration

Comment: After I run `heroku run python manage.py migrate myBlog zero` I get: _
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "myBlog_category" does not exist
LINE 1: ...g_category"."name", "myBlog_category"."name" FROM "myBlog_ca..._
My models.py for members app is empty, just an import of models from django.db. 
In migrations folder of members app I got empty __init__.py file, and __pycache__ folder with a .pyc file

Comment: In myBlog app there are 12 .py migrations, from 0001 to 0012 as you can see in this picture : https://imgur.com/a/Y4fNZF9

Comment: @OctavianAntoniuRăducanu Are you importing the Category model in some kind of migration? Or is there some model that has a foreign key to the category model?

Comment: The Category model is used for certain views, I added the views.py file to the original post. Sorry I can't write you in private, not enough reputation on StackOverflow. 
Also Category Model is used in forms.py file, for it to appear as a choice list when you post a new blog post.
`choices = Category.objects.all().values_list('name', 'name')
choice_list = []
for item in choices:
    choice_list.append(item)`

Comment: It seems that Category model is referenced through foreign key by another model. Could you attach your forms.py also?